# How to save a texture from texture atlas

Tags: uv, export, uv-image-editor

i'm new on Blender and i'm trying to learn much things everyday through tutorials.
Now i'm trying to make a Spyro fan game with Unity using Blender to create textured models but i'm having some problems.
To make a Spyro fan game i have to use the Texture Atlas method (used to make textures ps1 style)

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1MouKWH6IM&t=23s

Now i'm stuck here
[image]

I really don't know how to export the texture and use it then on Unity
On the right you can see that tried to mess with the Texture tab not having success

Answer (score 1):

Since the image is being displayed in the UV/Image Editor you can go to the menu in the bottom left of that window and choose Image > Save As Image.

This is standard functionality of the UV/Image Editor, whether you're using the Texture Atlas add-on or not.